# Duplicate data.table rows from formatted string column

Tags: r, data.table

#### Question:

What is the best way in R to transform a `data.table` which looks like this:

```
> input
   id value        node
1:  1   foo       node3
2:  2   bar   node[2,4]
3:  3   qux   node[2-4]
4:  4   foo node[1-2,4]
```

into something like this:

```
> output
   id value  node
1:  1   foo node3
2:  2   bar node2
3:  2   bar node4
4:  3   qux node2
5:  3   qux node3
6:  3   qux node4
7:  4   foo node1
8:  4   foo node2
9:  4   foo node4
```

Sample input and output:

`input <- data.table(id = c(1,2,3,4), value = c("foo", "bar", "qux", "foo"), node = c("node3","node[2,4]","node[2-4]","node[1-2,4]"))`

`output <- data.table(id = c(1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4), value = c("foo","bar","bar","qux","qux","qux","foo","foo","foo"), node = c("node3", "node2", "node4", "node2", "node3", "node4", "node1", "node2", "node4"))`

#### Background:

I am extracting job logs from a cluster of machines and the logs are similar to the input above. The id corresponds to a job id, the value to a particular executable, and the node to the machines in the cluster that actually executed the job. The logs use a compressed formatting for the node column to represent which machines the job ran on.

Using `library(stringr)`, I wrote some ugly code which will partially parse the node column. Perhaps this can be a useful starting point:

```
  expand_node <- function(nodes)
  {
    tokens <- str_match(nodes, "\\[([0-9,\\-]+)\\]")[ ,2]
    tokens <- str_replace_all(tokens, "\\-", ":")
    tokens <- paste0("c(",tokens,")")
    result <- lapply(tokens, function(expr) eval(parse(text = expr)))
    return(result)
  }
```

Comment: Does the node number go above 10?

Comment: It does, unfortunately.

Comment: Then I would probably take similar approach as yours if I had this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `data.table` option you can try, and one step fewer with the regular expression:

```
input[, .(node = unlist(lapply(sub("node\\[?([0-9,:]+)\\]?", "c(\\1)", gsub("-", ":", node)), 
          function(expr) paste("node", eval(parse(text = expr)), sep = "")))), .(id, value)]

#   id value  node
#1:  1   foo node3
#2:  2   bar node2
#3:  2   bar node4
#4:  3   qux node2
#5:  3   qux node3
#6:  3   qux node4
#7:  4   foo node1
#8:  4   foo node2
#9:  4   foo node4
```

Comment: This `lapply` stuff is not needed: `input[, .(node = paste0(
    "node", 
    eval(parse(text = 
        sub("node\\[?([0-9,:]+)\\]?", "c(\\1)", gsub("-", ":", node))
    ))
)), by = .(id, value)]`

Comment: @Frank This causes some problem if the data has multiple rows for a group but it looks like each row has a unique id. Your approach probably is better suited for OP's data.

Comment: Nice use of the built-in regex functionality, great `data.table` wizardry! Also, I can always add a `unique id` column.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using `cSplit` after changing the 'node' column

```
library(stringr)
library(splitstackshape)
library(gsubfn)
input[, node := lapply(str_extract_all(gsubfn("(\\d+)-(\\d+)", 
     ~seq(as.numeric(x), as.numeric(y), by = 1), node), "[0-9]+"), 
        function(x) paste0("node", x, collapse=","))]
cSplit(input, "node", ",", "long")
#   id value  node
#1:  1   foo node3
#2:  2   bar node2
#3:  2   bar node4
#4:  3   qux node2
#5:  3   qux node3
#6:  3   qux node4
#7:  4   foo node1
#8:  4   foo node2
#9:  4   foo node4
```

Comment: I was working on the same idea and was doing something like `input.df %>% separate_rows(new1, sep = ',') %>% select(id, value, new1)` ... :)